# how to get desired text from element in linkedin scraping using python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Below 'a' element has two text strings "First Name" and "View First Names's profile". With below python code using get_text() I am getting both the text strings. However I want to get only first i.e. "First Name". Pl let me know code to drop 2nd string i.e. "View First Names's profile"

---

```
all_classes = src.find_all('div', {'class':'mb1'})
for linkClass in all_classes:
    linkClass = linkClass.find_all('a', {'class': 'app-aware-link'})
    for element in linkClass:
        name = element.get_text().strip()
        Name.append(name)
```

---

HTML

```html
<a class="app-aware-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/shreyansjain-iitdhn?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAABpqUi4Bg1wC5QB22-ydCRRB580Zd4gutQ8">
    <span dir="ltr">
        <span aria-hidden="true"><!-- -->First Name<!-- --></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!-- -->View First Names’s profile<!-- --></span>
    </span>
</a>
```

[image: html]

Comment: can you clarify what element are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about 'a' tag <a class="app-aware-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/firstname-iitdhn?miniProfileUrn=urn%3Ali%3Afs_miniProfile%3AACoAABpqUi4Bg1wC5QB22-ydCRRB580Zd4gutQ8"> <span dir="ltr"First Name<span class="visually-hidden"View First Names’s profile </a>

Comment: On what linkedin page can I see it?

Comment: if you see in above 'a' tag first text string is 'First Name" and second text string is "View First Names’s profile". I want only first text string

Comment: Anyway, I see it's the first child element. Right?

Comment: yes, https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/?keywords=business%20analyst&origin=SWITCH_SEARCH_VERTICAL is actual linked page

Comment: I edited your question into something hopefully legible and with properly formatted html. Please ensure it retains your intended message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
all_classes = src.find_all('div', {'class':'mb1'})
for linkClass in all_classes:
    linkClass = linkClass.find_all('a', {'class': 'app-aware-link'})
    for element in linkClass:
        if element is not None:
            first_name = element.find_elements_by_xpath('./span/span')[0]       
            if first_name is not None:
                name = first_name.get_text().strip()
                Name.append(name)
```

Comment: but with your code, issue is if profile is hidden, in that case 'dir' wont b there  as shown. it will fail <a class="app-aware-link" href="https://www.linkedin.com/search/results/people/headless?origin=GLOBAL_SEARCH_HEADER&amp;keywords=business%20analyst%20AND%20gurgaon">
<!-- -->LinkedIn Member<!-- -->
</a>

Comment: any idea, if we come across hidden profile code pick text from 'a' tag without checking condition

Comment: getting error - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: i can get first string with condition ('span', {'aria-hidden':'true'}) but it fails if profile is hidden as 'aria-hidden' is not there and text string 'LinkedIn Member' is stored in 'a' tag only. If you can help with code so that it bypasses {'aria-hidden':'true'} condition when hidden profile comes across

Comment: Added validation for none type

Comment: first_name = element.find_element_by_xpath('.(/span/span)[1]')

Comment: I changed the none type validation for element itself. Hope now it will work correct. I see no hidden profiles here, so just can suggest things

Comment: ----> 6             first_name = element.find_element_by_xpath('.(/span/span)[1]')

Comment: Are you sure you copied my code with correct indentation?

Comment: I think I got the issue. See if it works correct now

Answer (score 0):

To extract the first name in Selenium I would do this :

use the below `CSS_SELECTOR` for First name :

```
.app-aware-link span[dir='ltr'] span:first-of-type
```

Profile name :

```
.app-aware-link span[dir='ltr'] span:last-of-type
```

and extract the text b/w them like this :

**first-name :**

```
for name in  driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, " .app-aware-link span[dir='ltr'] span:first-of-type"):
       print(name.text)
```

**Profile_name :**

```
for profile_name in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".app-aware-link span[dir='ltr'] span:last-of-type"):
       print(profile_name.text)
```

Comment: it works but issue is for hidden profiles where tags are different <a class="app-aware-link" href="linkedin.com/search/results/people/…"> <!-- -->LinkedIn Member<!-- --> </a>. 'dir' is not there and name "LinkedIn Member" is not getting picked. trying to use if else condition, but not getting it right

Comment: app-aware-link is a class then it has a span where attributes is `dir = ltr` for both. and in that we are looking for span (the 2nd one) using `last-of-type`. It is just visually hidden. I am pretty much sure we can scrape it. Give it a try and let me know

Comment: see this html  <a class="app-aware-link" href="linkedin.com/search/results/people/…"> <!-- -->LinkedIn Member<!-- --> </a>, there is no span and attribute 'dir'

Comment: for linkClass in all_classes:
    linkClass = linkClass.find_all('a', {'class': 'app-aware-link'})
    for element in linkClass:
        if element.get_attribute_list == 'aria-hidden':
            name = element.get_text()
        else:
            name = 'LinkedIn Membr'
        Name.append(name)

Comment: tried above code.. it is running successfully but it is returning only else condition values i.e "LinkedIn Member'. Not sure why if element.get_attribute_list == 'aria-hidden' is not working

Comment: tried to run your code with find_by_css_selector, only members with name are fetched, hidden profile with text "LinkedIn member are not getting picked"

Comment: @Junaid : What is the error for `LinkedIn member `

Comment: 'there was no error but it was not picking this text

Comment: got resolved now with this condition for element in linkClass:
        name = element.find('span',{'aria-hidden':'true'})
        if name:
            name=name.get_text()
        else:
            name='LinkedIn Member''